# How to use SQL-parser in node js?

Tags: sql, node.js, ejs, sql-parser

I am using node+ejs for rendering the pages. In one page I want to validate the SQL query syntax which is been entered. By searching I got to know     sql-parser is the way to do that but I don't know how to do.

Now my question is, how to use sql-parser to validate the query in nodejs.

since I am a beginner to this I don't have any idea. hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction.Thanks in Advance.

Ask me for more clarification.

Comment: Can you provide a link to sql-parse within the NPM site?  There are a few packages that have `sql-parser` in it so I'm not sure which one you mean.  Second, post some code if you have it showing what you've tried.  Third, a lot of these libraries have documentation on how to use them with code samples.  What exactly aren't you understanding about the library?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt, sorry sir for the late reply.Since I am new to this I don't know about the libraries. while searching I got to know sql-parser is the way. I referred from this link http://jsfiddle.net/Hb6az/

Comment: this is the functionality --> http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/vendor-specific-offline-sql-syntax-check/

Comment: So I can't get that JSFiddle working with that specific library you mentioned but if you are using Nodejs, I found a pretty good looking library here that might do the same thing for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sqlparser  It seems pretty lightweight and should still do what you want and tells you how to import it into your project.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will look into this in detail :)